# maven; how to break backwards compatibility?

Tags: java, api, maven, build, backwards-compatibility

Maven has a version management system that picks the highest version of a library if multiple versions are referenced. For example if a pom A refers to a version 1.1 and and pom B to 1.2, then a pom C (referring to both A and B) will use the highest version; 1.2.

This approach assumes that 1.2 is 100% backwards compatible with 1.1 and this is a good and required approach. However, at certain times in the lifecycle of libraries it is wise to clean up shop. For me any major changes in the API means increasing the major version, so a 2.0 does not need to be 100% backwards compatible to the latest 1.x. Fine.

Maven, however, does not really care and if pom B would be upgraded from 1.2 to 2.0, Maven would then use 2.0, but pom A cannot work with that version.

**How to tell Maven that a version is no longer backwards compatible?**

I've tried specifying excluding ranges, so A refers [1.1,1.999) and B refers [2.0,2.999). However, Maven still solves the maximum version number (2.0).

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  are you trying to get the build to break if incompatible versions are required?  or, are you trying to get maven to resolve the older version...?

Comment: The build should fail if two dependencies are present that use incompatible versions of the same library.

Comment: it would be impossible to include both dependency .jar files on the classpath and only the first one would be used anyway. What you are asking for isn't possible regardless of Maven behavior.

Answer (score 3):

First it's a bad practice to use [version ranges](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges.html) in Maven Builds furthermore you have to define a version numbering definition which says 1.0 and 1.1 must be backwards compatible whereas 2.0 is not but that's a definition you have to make. Maven does not know about that. I would recommend to use [Major.Minor.Increment-Qualifier](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html) etc. In my opinion you should pin your versions fix otherwise you are not able to reproduce your builds.

Comment: Gentoo has solved this by introducing the concepts of slots http://devmanual.gentoo.org/general-concepts/slotting/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I would change the artifact ID (probably by adding the major version number).  This would make the 1.x and 2.x versions different beasts to Maven.

Comment: You want the OP to change the artifact ID of an object when its major version changes? That seems extreme...

Comment: Wouldn't that simple result in two versions of the same library included in the classpath? TheLib1.jar and TheLib2.jar? The idea was to generate an error.

Comment: I'm not suggesting doing this for every artifact. Only those that break the API from one version to the next.  It's also not necessarily an ERROR to use two different APIs so long as they don't conflict internally.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the maven enforcer plugin?  it may have something like this, or you may be able to write a custom rule.